# Cartthrob Multi Location Settings Manager gives white screen of death

Tags: cartthrob

I upgraded CartThrob Pro to 2.4 and EE to 2.7.3 now I get a white screen of death when I try to access the Multi Location Settings Manager module page in the control panel. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it.

I am using the Multi Location Settings Manager to change shipping options for domestic vs. international orders.

I'm not using the HealthCheck accessory.

Anyone else have this problem? Any suggestions for debugging it?

Comment: I just updated CartThrob to the latest version, 2.5, and I still have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I installed here locally and on one of our remote servers. I found a few small things I fixed, but nothing that I would expect to create the "white screen of death". Barrett also installed in a few locations and didn't have issues, so it may be some specific conflict that's a bit hard to diagnose.

The latest public release is 1.677 of the Multi Location Module, available for free download from cartthrob.com. You might want to make sure that's updated.

Because we can't reproduce this here I suggest you schedule a Phone/Skype appointment with the CartThrob/Mightybigrobot support team at http://support.mightybigrobot.com. A member of our support team can speak with your personally and will custom tailor a suitable solution to this issue.